# Как скрыть диалог при старте?

Tags: winapi, c++, visual-c++

В моей программе нужно чтобы диалог создавался скрытым, а потом уже по мере надобности открывался. Добавил в `WM_INITDIALOG` вызов `ShowWindow(g_hWnd, SW_HIDE);`, но это не помогает и диалог все равно отображается. Сам диалог создаю так:

```
DialogBox(g_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MAIN_DIALOG), 0, (DLGPROC)DialogProc)
```

Как сделать диалог скрытым при старте?

Comment: Хм. А что мешает вызвать `DialogBox` именно в тот момент, когда он нужен?

Comment: Неудобно по структуре (придется две разные обработки в разных местах делать, вместо одной для обоих случае), и нужен HWND. В общем, хотелось бы именно скрывать окно.

Comment: @BArtWell: Тогда может попробуйте вместо этого `CreateWindowEx`?

Comment: Посмотрю, спасибо.